# Computer not booting (motherboard issue?)

Tags: boot

I recently moved to another state and upon plugging my PC in after the drive, it failed to move past the manufacturer's splash screen. Not being the smartest of people, I turned it off and tried again.

This time (and every time since) my keyboard lighting comes on, but numlock etc do nothing.
There is no manufacturer splash screen.
There is no further output from the machine.
The motherboard has LEDs, which seem fully functional.

As far as I can see there's no readout for post codes and I don't have a speaker handy, but I can probably find one in a store around here.
I also don't have another cpu handy, which I've seen suggested in other threads. Maybe time for an upgrade from skylake.

Comment: Can you tell us the computer brand name and model, that could help in solving your problem. Make sure the computer is plugged into an area where no other devices are being used except the computer and monitor.

Comment: The computer is custom built, full spec list can be found here https://steamcommunity.com/id/fish_potato
edit: only one monitor is connected currently

Comment: Did you try a different socket? The socket may have bad wiring which may not be able to supply enough power, or something. That's all I can think of which correlates the problem to moving states

Answer (score 0):

Did you build that? That is a great motherboard.

If you know how to build that I would try unplugging it, 
press the power button for about 10 seconds and open the case, 
remove the RAM stick(s) and put them back in. Remove the video 
card and put that back in also. Replace the cover and plug it 
back in.

If it still does not boot up correctly it maybe your CPU (Skylake) 
which needs to be reseated also. 

If all else fails, please visit your motherboard support page

> https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1012219
>   
> **[Motherboard] Recover the BIOS by using ASUS CrashFree BIOS 3**
>   
> Last Update : 2020/01/06 11:16.

There is also a video there to help assist you.

Support page is here: 
[PRIME Z270-P    FAQ](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-P/HelpDesk/)

I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Noctua NH-D14 is a pretty heavy cooler. If you didn’t take it off or immobilize it in some other way while transporting your PC, I’m afraid it could have physically damaged the motherboard.